# Appium how to send_keys to view controller?

Tags: ios, ruby, appium

I have a view controller with custom text input, that the view controller itself is taking care of. So the view controller is setting itself as first responder and updates a view based on the input.

The problem is that I am now trying to add automated UI tests for this screen with Appium and I cannot find a way to `send_keys` to the view controller.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create an xpath of the element on which the text needs to be typed and use it 
If your are using webview u need to switch context to webview

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me and it doesn't seem to have much to do with what I was asking for and it definitely doesn't answer my question.